# invalid entry form mapping. other mapping have the same name but have different id

Tags: bonita

I am getting the following error while working on a "getting started" tutorial from bonita website. Error image attached.

"invalid entry form mapping. other mapping have the same name but have different id in "

I have defined forms for Pool and Manager review task. The tutorial is from this site 
http://documentation.bonitasoft.com/getting-started-tutorial-2

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest to try to select again the form to display for process instantiation and step execution.

For process:

- select the pool
- go to "Execution" -> "Instantiation form"
- on the right hand side of "Target form" click on the eraser icon
- in the "Target form" drop down list select again the previous form

For "Manager review" step:

- select the "Manager review" step
- go to "Execution" -> "Form"
- follow the same steps as for the pool

You can refresh the diagram validation: from Studio "Diagram" menu select "Validate".

Answer (score 2):

If you have opened diagrams in UI designer - close them and then try to run the process. Worked for me.